# VPN not working

Tags: 16.04, vpn, openvpn, connection, pptp

I've been using VPN in Linux for quite some time but from some time now I get the connection but cannot access any site. I can connect to the VPN on other devices but not in Linux.
I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and I tried both pptp and openVPN.

Hope someone can help on this as have spend already a few days investigating and trying solutions.

Thank you.

By the way this is what I get in the IP route list
default@PO-UBUNTU:~$ ip route list

default dev ppp0  proto static  scope link  metric 50

default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp7s0  proto static  metric 100

79.172.193.105 via 192.168.1.1 dev enp7s0  src 192.168.1.2

169.254.0.0/16 dev enp7s0  scope link  metric 1000

172.111.129.2 via 192.168.1.1 dev enp7s0  src 192.168.1.2

172.111.129.4 dev ppp0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.111.129.15  metric 50

192.168.1.0/24 dev enp7s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.2  metric 100

Comment: See IP route list above